# Hibernate Transaction Context with Struts2 Actions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, struts2, spring-transactions, valuestack

I have a scenario where, a Struts2 action fetches a model object from back-end and puts it in to the OGNL stack and the front end view is updated with that data.

Then I change a value in the view that corresponds to the model object and update. Then that value is saved using Hibernate's  `getSession().update(model)` method.

**Question** : When the model object is read in to the OGNL stack, that transaction context closes and the model object gets **detached**. 
Why am I allowed to save the change using `getSession().update(model)`? 
I think `getSession().merge(model)` should be used.

Please help me to understand the ambiguity.

Comment: because you have your object in stack and when you are calling the update method spring will create new session and update the entity....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods can pass *detached* object as parameter, but if there's an object in the context with the given identifier, the first method throws an exception. Read

> Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached
>   instance. If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier,
>   an exception is thrown.

```
public void update(Object object);
```

The second method doesn't throw an exception because it loads not existing object by its identifier to the context, update it, and returns to the caller.

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same
>   identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with
>   the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the
>   given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent
>   instance. The given instance does not become associated with the session.

```
public Object merge(Object object);
```